# How to properly define Higher Order Component in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to learn HOC in reactjs and trying to understand this basic example..

I have 3 files named First.js, Second.js and App.js. Now how I need to define those files so that computation done in first file should be accessible to second file.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import First from './First';
import Second from './Second';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={First}/>
          <Route exact path='/Second' component={Second}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

First.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Second from './Second';
class First extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      number : 1,
    };
  }
  increment = event => {
    this.setState({
      number : this.state.number + 1
    });
  }
  decrement = event => {
    this.setState({
      number : this.state.number - 1
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.number}
        <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
        <Second number={this.state.number}/>
        <Link to='/Second'>Second</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default First;
```

Second.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class Second extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.number}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Second;
```

I want to access First.js variable in second.js. Give me solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What variable you want to access in second.js component?

Comment: number @Think-Twice

Comment: Are you not getting the number value in Second component?

Comment: No. When I press on link I am not getting anything.

Comment: You won’t get number values because in routes you must be passing number value to Second component from routes

Comment: Can you show me how to pass in routes?

Comment: You get the number only when first calls second component because you are explicitly sending number value as props to Second component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181714/discussion-between-yash-choksi-and-think-twice).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <Route path="/Second" render={()=> (
      <div>
         100
      </div>
  )}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above implementation that you have shown isn't of an HOC, rather a simple Route implementation, Since you are rendering the Second component inside of `First` you would want to render the `/second` route inside first

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import First from './First';
import Second from './Second';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' component={First}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

First.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Second from './Second';
class First extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      number : 1,
    };
  }
  increment = event => {
    this.setState({
      number : this.state.number + 1
    });
  }
  decrement = event => {
    this.setState({
      number : this.state.number - 1
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.number}
        <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
        <Route path="/Second" render={(props)=> <Second number={this.state.number} {...props}/>} />
        <Link to='/Second'>Second</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default First;
```

Comment: I suggested the same answer from routes file but not directly in Second component. But the problem seems he always get number undefined in Second component irrespective of how the Secondcomponet is called. Also in your answer Route path should be /Second s should be capital letter.

Comment: @Think-Twice, the reason number is undefined is because when /Second route is visited the Route in App.js is matched where number is not passed as a prop

Comment: I do suggested same answer that you gave but in return he came back to me with following warning index.js:1452 Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route render> in the same route; <Route render> will be ignored

Comment: @Think-Twice, that could be because he would have used both component and render prop in the Route which is evident from the warning